# How to convert a POST API call with a JSON body to a java class in Springboot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

i'm passing a POST request with raw JSON body which holds the configuration details, i want to save it as a java class so i can distribute the data using getters to relevant classes that need the config details specified for them.This is the body of my request

```
{
"aisles" : 2,
"sections" : 2,
"shelves" : 1,
"packagingAreas": [ "a1.3", "a2.3" ],
"workers" : [
    {
        "name" : "rem",
        "location" : "a1.1",
        "capacity" : 20
    }
],
"items" : [
    {
        "id" : "mars",
        "name" : "Mars",
        "supplier" : "Nestle",
        "weight" : 1
    },
    {
        "id" : "kitkat",
        "name" : "Kit Kat",
        "supplier" : "Nestle",
        "weight" : 1
    },
    {
        "id" : "dd",
        "name" : "Double Decker",
        "supplier" : "Nestle",
        "weight" : 1
    }
]
}
```

and i want to the details of that body into my config.java class, this is the config.java class

```
public class Config {

    private static String aisles;
    private static String sections;
    private static String shelves;
    private static String packagingAreas[];
    private static ArrayList<Worker> workers;
    private static ArrayList<Item> items;

    public static String getAisles() {
        return aisles;
    }

    public static String getSections() {
        return sections;
    }

    public static String getShelves() {
        return shelves;
    }

    public static String[] getPackagingAreas() {
        return packagingAreas;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Worker> getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

And i have modelled the worker and item classes with the same variables as in the json configuration file, is there a direct way to convert this JSON file to a class? if not what other methods can i try?
Thanks in advance!

edit- This is the endpoint i have created, using @Rest Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/config", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void configure() {
   //i want to do the conversion here
  }
```

Comment: im sending the post request through POSTMAN, to an endpoint i defined using the REST controller, it's an empty method, i want to implement the conversion there,

Comment: @RequestMapping(value ="/config", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void configure() {
    
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update the controller as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/config", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public void configure(@RequestBody Config config) {
  //your json is converted to config java object
}
```

2. Update your `Config` class

```
public class Config {
    private String aisles;
    private String sections;
    private String shelves;
    private String packagingAreas[];
    private ArrayList<Worker> workers;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public void setAisles(String aisles) {
        this.aisles = aisles;
    }

    public void setSections(String sections) {
        this.sections = sections;
    }

    public void setShelves(String shelves) {
        this.shelves = shelves;
    }

    public void setPackagingAreas(String[] packagingAreas) {
        this.packagingAreas = packagingAreas;
    }

    public void setWorkers(ArrayList<Worker> workers) {
        this.workers = workers;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getAisles() {
        return aisles;
    }

    public String getSections() {
        return sections;
    }

    public String getShelves() {
        return shelves;
    }

    public String[] getPackagingAreas() {
        return packagingAreas;
    }

    public ArrayList<Worker> getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

**Explanation**
By default spring boot comes with several `HttpMessageConverter`s enabled. One of them is `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` which converts your json to java object.

See this [http message converter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest)

Comment: will this convert the workers section of the json msg into objects of my Worker class as well?